# Is $\sin(x) = O(1)$, as $x\to \infty$?

Tags: linear-algebra, asymptotics

I read through a lot of literature and it feels like the more I read, the more confused I become. For this question, I argued that as $x$ tends to $\infty$, the value of $\sin(x)$ would oscillate between $-1$ and $1$ only and you cannot fix a specific constant or a function to represent its growth. But some others are saying that since the sine function is bounded between -1 and 1, $| \sin(x) | \le 1$, which is the definition of $O$ notation, it is true. Are there any steps that I can follow to evaluate whether the notation is true or not?

Comment: Do you know the definition of $O(1)$?  Do you agree that $|\sin(x)| \le 1$?  Does that satisfy the definition?

Comment: @Robert Yes, I agree that $\left| \sin(x) \right| \le 1$ for any value of x. From what I know, $O(1)$ represents that the function $\text{f(x)}$ has a constant growth rate of 1. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Your problem is that you are thinking that the $O$ notation is used to give a function that represents its growth. For example, it follows from the definition of the $O$ notation that $x+1 = O(x)$ but also that $x+1=O(x^2)$ and also that $x+1 = O(e^x)$, and that doesn't mean that $e^x$ represents the growth of $x+1$.

Comment: @jjagmath Is it not possible to say that the growth of function can be represented using other functions , but different constants multiplied to it?

Comment: Yes, but the notation for that is not $f(x)=O(g(x))$. It's usually $f(x) =\Theta (g(x))$ or $f(x) \asymp g(x)$

Comment: Please state the definition of $f(x) = O(1)$! It seems you do not perfectly grasp what it means.

Comment: This equation ($\varphi(t) = O(\varphi(t))$) asserts that there exists some positive constant C such that, for all t sufficiently close to an understood limit (e.g $t\to 0$ or $t\to \infty$,
$\left| \varphi(t) \right| = C \varphi(t)$
This is from the textbook that I'm following, Numerical Linear Algebra, Trefethen and Bau